# Accessing properties from an observable in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

This might be a simple question but can't figure it out.
When I load up my site I call a service that fetches user data

```js
private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser>(1);
currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();
// call to controller left out for brevity
// then pass user to replaysubject here
this.currentUserSource.next(user);
```

I can access the values in my html file with an async call like this

```html
(currentUser$ | async).someProperty
```

But how do I access the values in typescript?

Comment: I think you need to subscribe in the typescript file and then reference the variable in template

Comment: do you have short example you can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the event:

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs";

const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);

subject.subscribe((user) => {
    console.log('User Id:', user.id);
});

subject.next({ 
     id: 1, 
     name: "jon"
});
```

Comment: np,@user1186050 if it helped, I would appreciate if you accept the answer as well